# Data transfer to imported file from other imported file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 files:

dgen.py - Used to generate some data in lists

```
import random, time, threading

data = []

def udata():
    while True:
        data.append(random.randint(1,1000))
        time.sleep(1)
        if len(data)>10:
            data.pop(0)

def start():
    threading.Thread(target=udata,).start()
```

main.py - Used to transfer generated data to prev_data.py

```
from gden import data, start
from prev_data import pstart, d

start()
pstart()

while True:
    d = data
    #print(data)
```

prev_data.py - Used to display the generated lists

```
import time, threading

d = []
def pdata():
    while True:
        print(d,1)
        time.sleep(1)

def pstart():
    threading.Thread(target = pdata, ).start()
```

The problem is that 'prev_data.py' list 'd' is not updating!
Please tell a solution to update the variable 'd'(of prev_data.py) from the 'main.py' file!

Comment: Your primary problem is that `d = data` creates a new `d` variable inside of the `main` module - it doesn't touch `prev_data.d` at all.